# Git Repository Access denied

Tags: windows, git

I'm getting permission denied errors when trying to pull or commit to my git repo hosted on assembla. I generated the ssh key pair more than once and added the public key to assembla, but that did not resolve the issue.

I am using two computers using the Git bash on Windows.
It was working perfectly fine on computerA. Then when I pulled down changes from computerB from the same repo, I lost access to my repo from computerA.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@gmail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/u//.ssh/id_rsa): C:\Users\agallagher\.ssh\id_rsa
C:\Users\agallagher\.ssh\id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in C:\Users\agallagher\.ssh\id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\agallagher\.ssh\id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:


agallagher@LPW7-5CG6181LYY MINGW64 /c/alicia_code_repo (master)
$ git pull
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

git clone git@git.assembla.com:myrepo.git

Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: If you generate a new key, you need to register the new public key in your assembla.

Comment: @poke, I already did that. The public key has been uploaded to assembla. Do I need to do a git remote add origin?